# semantic difference for the forms: "x of y" vs. "x of the y" vs. "y x"

Tags: meaning, phrases, phrase-requests, semantics, syntactic-analysis

As a non-native speaker, I have a problem understanding the difference in meaning of the following forms:

- "… of …"
- "… of the …"
- "… …"

To be more specific, let me give some instances:

- "theory of mind" vs. "theory of the mind" vs. "mind theory"
- "theory of activity" vs. "activity theory"
- "theory of action" vs. "action theory"

While writing, I naïvely notice that there is a difference in nature between my first example and the two latter… I fail to understand exactly why, either… I don't know why, but while "theory of the mind" sounds understandable to me, "theory of the activity" or "theory of the action" sounds less correct (maybe because we can speak about "the mind" as a generality, while "the action" or "the activity" needs to be specified?).

Any help would be much appreciated,

Many thanks

Comment: Noun compounds can get pinned down to specific meanings; not every white house is The White House, and theories can get strange names. So, not all compounds are descriptive. With that caveat, there is no real difference between the forms. _Of_ is sort of an all-purpose totally meaningless connector, and it allows us an extra syllable when we want it. That's all, really.

Comment: ***of*** http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/206004/the-use-of-preposition-of

Comment: **the** http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/grammar-when-not-to-use-the-definite-article/

Comment: "mind theory" is a word (a compound noun), while "theory of mind" is a phrase.  (Well, I guess that isn't a semantic difference, though.)

Comment: Ok, thank you for your comments, it helps a bit. So, your point is that semantically, there might be just no difference between compound noun and phrase version? At least, it depends on the context, or the object of the emphasising, right?

Mhhh, now, what would be the more natural way? In everyday english, is it more common to make use of compound nouns, or phrases?

Comment: "of" might also be a possessive connector. Is it less used than "'s" in this context? Conversely, do we use the "'s" for inanimate objects? And, is it correct?

(like the "truck's wheel", vs. "the truck wheel", vs. "the wheel of the truck")

("the John's hand", vs. "the hand of John")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are astute in observing the subtle difference with "mind". I think you got that right.

As for the others, there is a slight connotative difference between, say, "theory of action" and "action theory". The first is clearly a theory about action and its causes. The second might be proposing "action" as an explanation or cause of something else.

Consider, for example, Brown's motion theory (or rather Einstein's motion theory, as borne out by Brown's experimental observations) which is now accepted as an explanation for how temperature change "works".